Can I specify the xml name space in a wix XmlFile Element?
I have a wix installer and I need it add some xml elements to a config file.
Here is the xml file before:
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
    </startup>
</configuration>

This is what I need the config file to look like after I run the installer:
<?xml version ="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
    </startup>
    <runtime>
        <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
            <probing privatePath="Hamilton MPE2"/>
        </assemblyBinding>
    </runtime>
</configuration>

I can add the runtime element successfully using this code block.
<util:XmlFile Id="AddRunTime" Action="createElement" ElementPath="//configuration" Permanent="no" File="[VENUSBINFOLDER]HxRun.exe.config" SelectionLanguage="XPath" Sequence="1" Name="runtime" />

However the assemblyBinding and probing have attributes that I am not sure how to specify. I looked at this and tried to add the attributes for the assmblyBinding element like this:
        <ComponentGroup Id="UpdateHxRun" Directory="BINFOLDER">
            <Component Id="UpdateHxRun" KeyPath="yes" Guid="13fe603b-feb2-402d-bfe5-8b649eb04e53">
                <util:XmlFile Id="AddRunTime" Action="createElement" ElementPath="//configuration" Permanent="no" File="[VENUSBINFOLDER]HxRun.exe.config" SelectionLanguage="XPath" Sequence="1" Name="runtime" />
                <util:XmlConfig  Id="AddAssemblyBinding" Action="create" ElementPath="//configuration//runtime" File="[VENUSBINFOLDER]HxRun.exe.config" Sequence="2" Name="assemblyBinding" Node="document">
                    <![CDATA[
            <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"> </assemblyBinding>
  ]]>
                </util:XmlConfig>
            </Component>
        </ComponentGroup>

That doesn't seem to add the xmlns value that I need.
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
    </startup>
<runtime/></configuration>

How do I properly specify attributes to xml elements in a wix installer>
